# Can not get textbox value inside datalist

Tags: asp.net, ajax, datalist

I am trying to get the value of textbox "Qty" inside a datalist.  It does not work.  What is wrong?  I have both the CartItem label and the datelist inside the ajax updatepanel.  Thanks for any help. Here is my code:

```
<asp:Label ID="CartItems" runat="server" Text="CartItem"></asp:Label>
<br />
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" CellPadding="10" 
 DataKeyField="product_id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" RepeatColumns="2">
 <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="product_id" runat="server" 
         Text='<%# Eval("product_id") %>' /><br/>
    <asp:Label ID="product_name" runat="server" 
         Text='<%# Eval("product_name") %>' />
  <br />
  Qty
  <br/>

    <asp:TextBox ID="Qty" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="ButtonAddToCart" runat="server" Text="Add to Cart" 
         onClick="ButtonAddToCart_Click"/>                    

    <br />
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

and here is the button click event.  The CartItem has null value:

```
 protected void ButtonAddToCart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        CartItem.Text = DataList1.FindControl("Qty").ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    TextBox Qty = (TextBox)DataList1.FindControl("Qty");
if(Qty != null)
{
    CartItem.Text =Qty.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NamingContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.namingcontainer.aspx) or `Parent` to access sibling controls

```
protected void ButtonAddToCart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button = sender as Button;
    var textbox = button.NamingContainer.FindControl("Qty") as TextBox;
    CartItem.Text = textbox.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer you to use item_command event of the datalist
do some think like this.

```
  <asp:Label ID="CartItems" runat="server" Text="CartItem"></asp:Label>
  <br />
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" CellPadding="10" DataKeyField="product_id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" RepeatColumns="2">
 <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:Label ID="product_id" runat="server" 
     Text='<%# Eval("product_id") %>' /><br/>
<asp:Label ID="product_name" runat="server" 
     Text='<%# Eval("product_name") %>' />
 <br />
 Qty
<br/>

<asp:TextBox ID="Qty" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="ButtonAddToCart" runat="server" Text="Add to Cart" CommandName="addtocart2"   OnCommand="DataList1_ItemCommand"
    />                    

<br />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Here is the item_command event that works.

```
 public void DataList1_ItemCommand(object source, System.Web.UI.WebControls.CommandEventArgs e){
 TextBox qtytxtbox =  DataList1.FindControl("Qty") as TextBox;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
protected void ButtonAddToCart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Button ButtonAddToCart= (Button)sender;
    DataListItem item = (DataListItem)ButtonAddToCart.NamingContainer;
    var textbox = (TextBox)item.FindControl("Qty");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
TextBox txtquantity = (TextBox)(e.Item.FindControl("Qty"));
```

simply use this......You will get the value in `txtquantity`